# How to put a ListItemLabel into a ListProperty

Tags: python, kivy

The ListItemLabel accepts only strings. I want to give it more than one element in a list, I use in ListItemLabel front str, but it does not do anything.

Python:

```
result_true = ListProperty([])

extra = self.viewedit.adapter.data 

for edit in extra: 
    if edit['active'] == True:

        app.result_true.append(edit['text'])
        #app.result_true = (edit['text'])
        print app.result_true
```

Kivy:

```
ListItemLabel:
   text:str(ctx.edit)
```

Return:

> ['\xce\xbb\xce\xb9\xce\xb1\xcf\x83\xcf\x84\xce\xae \xce\xbd\xcf\x84\xce\xbf\xce\xbc\xce\xac\xcf\x84\xce\xb1', '\xcf\x83\xce\xbf\xcf\x85\xcf\x83\xce\xac\xce\xbc\xce\xb9', '\xcf\x84\xcf\x85\xcf\x81\xce\xaf']